# Passing int arrays as arguments in methods [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arguments, argument-passing

I am building a Connect 4 game and I was wondering if it is possible to build int arrays into methods.  It would be easier for me to just show the code, so I've shown the method below (and dependencies).  The commented out bit is how it works at the moment

```
    //Defend 4 horizontal to the right (xxx-)
    for(int y=0;y<board.get_ysize();y++){
        boolean breakfor=false;
        for(int x=0;x<(board.get_xsize()-3);x++){
            if(board.get_state(x,y)==1
                    && board.areSame(board, {(x+1),y}, {x,y})
                    && board.areSame(board, {(x+2),y}, {x,y})
                    && board.areSame(board, {(x+3),y}, {0})

// How the code works at the moment:                        
//                      board.get_state((x+1),y)==board.get_state(x,y)
//                      && board.get_state((x+2),y)==board.get_state(x,y)
//                      && board.get_state((x+3),y)==0)
                    {
                if(y==0){
                    return (x+3);
                }
                else if((y-1)==0){
                    return (x+3);
                }
                else{
                    breakfor=true;
                    break;
                }       
            }
        }
        if(breakfor){
            break;
        }
    }
```

get_state():

```
public int get_state(int x, int y) {
        return layout[x][y];
    }
```

(layout[x][y] returns a 0, 1 or 2 for the position. 0 is empty and 1 and 2 are player counters)

areSame():

```
public boolean areSame(GameBoard board, int[] initialspace, int[] comparespace){
    if(board.get_state(initialspace[0],initialspace[1])==board.get_state(comparespace[0], comparespace[1])){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's not necessary as the code works the old way, but I was just wondering if there is a way to make this array method work?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for patterns to pass in to a method to check for?

Comment: I want to compare the type of counter (or lack of counter) in a space and in adjacent spaces to check if the player is about to win by placing a fourth counter. This is for a game AI, so it will always be checking if there is a 1 in the layout array positions as a 1 indicates a player counter.
I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check for a defense against a vertical and horizontal threat to win on next move by using a check like (for horizontal shown below, make an analog for vertical threat)

```
boolean threat;
int playX = -1;
int playY;

for (int y=0; y < board.get_ysize; y++) {
    for (int x=0, x < board.get_xsize; x++) {
        int count1;
        int count2;
        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            switch (board.get_state(x+i, y)) {
            case 0:
                if (playX == -1) {playX = x+i; playY = y;}
                break;
            case 1:
                count1++;
                break;
            case 2:
                count2++;
                break;
            default:
              // handle error
              break;
           }
        }
        if (count1 == 3 && count2 == 0) {
          // should be able to defend
          // play player 2 at playX, playY
        break; // could go on to see if imminent loss anyway
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a really neat way of win-checking actually! Thanks very much! :)